# How to properly design model's calculated fields in DDD?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I am becoming a big fan of [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). So, I'm thinking of applying it correctly to my current system I develop.

Suppose we have two aggregate roots: `Order` and `User`. `Order` has two properties, referencing the `User`: `owner` and `contractor`. Owner created an `Order`, contractor fulfilled it.

Owners can rate the quality with which the `Order` was fulfilled by the contractor. So we have an `Feedback` entity, connected to `Order`, containing rating.

Now, `User` object contains an average rating of each user across the orders he fulfilled. And this part confuses me a little.

`User` rating is not just a static property, but actually an average of all ratings across `Feedbacks`. And it is changed (needs to be recalculated) at the moment an `Order` has `Feedback` attached.

Currently I have some services encapsulating domain logic: `OrderService` and `UserService` (I know this is actually not in compliance with DDD, but I will refactor that later). When OrderService receives a command to attach Feedback to order, it emits `OrderFeedbackAttachedEvent` which UserService listens for to recalculate user rating.

What doesn't satisfy me is that the knowledge about Order aggregate root is now leaked into UserService. And I don't see the way to escape it. I'm starting to think there should be some pattern to handle such cases.

Rating seem to be a perfect property of the user. But the fact that it is not a static, persistent value, but rather something, that is calculated based on other objects data, makes me doubt.

Rating isn't itself an entity either. Neither it is a value object. What is it, I wonder, in DDD? And how do I model ratings (or any other calculatable value) in my system without sacrificing performance and ease of use)?

Comment: @plalx I am worried by the fact, that after feedback was given, all feedbacks must be aggregated to calculate user rating. That creates a dependency from user to order (calling order repository to fetch rating from user service, when event was caught). Is this ok, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, an event emitted from another AR or another BC is not leakage. There's no problem for a `User` AR to handle an `OrderFeedbackGiven` event in my opinion. If the `Feedback` VO is part of the event then the client doesn't need to depend on anything else to process the event. Having a feedback bounded context might be cleaner, but I wouldn't implement a full blown BC for just that or you will have an explosion of micro-BCs...

> I am worried by the fact, that after feedback was given, all
>   feedbacks must be aggregated to calculate user rating. That creates a
>   dependency from user to order (calling order repository to fetch
>   rating from user service, when event was caught). Is this ok, what do
>   you think?

I think it wouldn't matter if you did that. The application service layer is depending on the domain layer as a whole. However, there's no need to do this at all since you can calculate the [moving cumulative average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

E.g. Where `this.ordersFeedbackAvg` is a `MovingAvg` value object that keeps track of the average and how many data points it was computed from.

`when(OrderFeedbackGiven feedback) {
    this.ordersFeedbackAvg = this.ordersFeedbackAvg.cumulate(feedback.mark);
}`

Comment: Thanks for a good idea!

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny My example is incomplete as it doesn't model an average for individual orders and I didn't pay lot of attention to the language, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks!

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny Another aspect I haven't mentioned in my answer is concurrency. Do you really need the `User` entity to hold the feedback averages? Right now any other command involving the `User` AR may concurrently conflict with handling an `OrderFeedbackGiven` event. Since this moving average is eventually consistent anyway you may create another AR responsible for that only, which would decrease contention on the `User` AR. Is there any reason why the average was part of the `User` AR? Did you use that information in any command processed by this AR?

Comment: Well, concurrency can be a problem. But the rate of adding new feedbacks is like 1-5 per day so I'm not much worried currently. If I move into moving average, I will have to do some locking in place, may be with SELECT FOR UPDATE.

Comment: Do not forget that queries don't have to be made against the domain model, so data may be aggregated from many ARs for a single view. Are your events processing single-threaded or many events can be handled at once? Another strategy when eventual consistency is used is to accept many requests at a time, but process them in a single-threaded way. Therefore, if you had an AR dedicated to feedback average you wouldn't even need locking using this approach.

Comment: Yep. I am not actually worried about implementation currently. I started to learn OO design, so the most interesting here is the theory.

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny Great! Then I think the best piece of advice I may give you is that you should forget queries entirely when you design your object model. The domain model is meant to fulfill commands and protect invariants by creating ARs which are transactional boundaries. On the other hand, queries will often cross those boundaries, therefore it's better not to query the domain model and go directly to the DB in my opinion. It's not necessary to have full-fledged CQRS however (different DB + async projections)...

Comment: thanks :) I will think about that

Answer (score 7):

It appears you might have at least 2 separated bounded contexts: one for ordering, and another for feedbacks.

Aknowleging Bounded Contexts allows you to see different abstractions of the same physical thing: in the "orders" context, Order seems to be a legitimate Aggregate, but it could be a Value Object in the "feedback" BC, where it would hold an order id (which value comes from the order BC through an event).

Here is a proposal :

[image]
[image]

With this model, you would calculate the average rating of a contractor when handling the "FeedbackEmitted" event from the feedback aggregate in an event handler of the contractor aggregate

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What did you use to create your diagrams?

Comment: @DavidOsborne : I used http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/ 
The syntax is documented at http://plantuml.com/

Comment: @Mehdi. Thx for the amazing tool!